# Azure Static web app disable anonymous access

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app

I am using  Azure static Web app service [Static Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/static/).

Is there a way to disable anonymous access and apply security rules?

Comment: Add a `web.config file`, refer to the `web.config` of the .net web program, and apply the following `<deny user="?">` application to prevent anonymous access to static website resources.

Comment: As for security rules, what effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: Whether your application is in .net framework or dotnet core, or in other languages, you need to provide more details to help you.

Comment: I am hosting HTML static files, there is no server technology in the picture

Comment: Pls create a web.config file, then try.

Comment: If you do not find a better solution, I have updated my answer. You can quickly migrate your project to Asp.Net according to my suggestions, and you can get a better experience in Azure WebApp.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - there is way.

A simple example:

If you create a `routes.json` file [at the root of app's build artifact folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/routes) and put something like the following in the file:

```
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "route": "/login",
            "serve": "/.auth/login/aad"
        },
        {
            "route": "/*",
            "serve": "/index.html",
            "allowedRoles": [
                "reader",
                "owner",
                "contributor"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "platformErrorOverrides": [
        {
            "errorType": "Unauthenticated",
            "statusCode": "302",
            "serve": "/login"
        }
    ]
}
```

This will prompt the user to authenticate using Azure AD and serve the static webpage `index.html` only if authentication is successful and the authenticated user has one of the `allowedRoles`.

In order to assign a user roles, you have to invite them e.g. by using the

`Home > {static web app name} > Role management`

tab on `portal.azure.com`, and invite a user making sure to set the appropriate role.